# How to sum a column within a subset of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I am very new to Python and its application to GIS.

Using Jupyter notebook, I am dealing with a dataset too big to be opened with excel. It has almost 800000 rows and 61 columns.

Now, I need to query the dataframe in order to create the subset of interest, in this case 2 columns: OBJECTID and Landuse, each of them up to a specific range:

```
import pandas
df = pd.read_csv('.big file.csv')
grass_ID4440 = df[(df.OBJECTID == 4440) & (df.Landuse == 'Grass - Urban')]
```

This subset spits out 38 rows. Now, If I wanted to sum the area of just those 38 rows, which logic/approach should I take?

Here is my thinking:

```
area_ID4440 = grass_ID4440['Area'].sum()
```

It's obviously wrong in terms of logic because it spits out the sum of the TOTAL area of the entire dataset.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As far as I can see `grass_ID4440` contains just the needed 38 rows, so using `grass_ID4440['Area'].sum()` can only sum the area of those.

Comment: Please show desired output since the single sum appears to answer *I wanted to sum the area of just those 38 rows*.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic *should* work fine. But it's worth pointing out that you should *avoid* chained indexing, [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) in the docs, wherever possible. This removes ambiguity of using a copy versus a view, but also makes your logic clearer.

There are a couple of options:-

#### Reuse Boolean indexing

A common method is to calculate a Boolean mask (the expensive part) and reuse it in subsequent calculations:

```
mask = (df['OBJECTID'] == 4440) & (df['Landuse'] == 'Grass - Urban')
grass_ID4440 = df[mask]  # this is a view based on df
area_ID4440 = df.loc[mask, 'Area'].sum()  # scalar output
```

#### Make an explicit copy

This way, any changes to your dataframe slice will not affect your original dataframe:

```
mask = (df['OBJECTID'] == 4440) & (df['Landuse'] == 'Grass - Urban')
grass_ID4440 = df[mask].copy()  # this is a copy, changes will not be reflected in df
area_ID4440 = df.loc[mask, 'Area'].sum()  # scalar output
```